# how to iterate over the output of jquery.map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

<strike>**Is it possible to iterate over the value returned by jQuery's `$.map` function?**</strike>

**Update:** The problem was that I was returning a jQuery object in the first iterator
`return $('row').append(generateItem(response.items,item,index));`
Once I returned a regular object, it worked fine.

Edit: Thanks to suggestions below, I have figured out how to iterate over the output of a `$.map` function. However, **I am still unable to manipulate the output of `$.map`**

TLDR; Iteration#1- `generateItem()` returns a jQuery object. 
      Iteration#2 tries to append select portions of the returned jQuery object to DOM elements. This doesn't work.

```
$($.map(response.items, function(item, index){
    // don't wrap this in a $() selector
    return generateItem(response.items,item,index);

    })).each(function(index,question){
      console.log(question)
      // => [prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1], context: document, selector: "row", jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function…]

      var container = $('<article>').addClass('row');

      // With header, I am trying to grab the jQuery object returned by the $.map function, but it fails         
      var header = $(question).find('header');
      console.log(question) // => x.fn.x.init[0] 

      var sidebar = $('<section>').addClass('col-md-4 sidebar').html(header);
      var body = $(question).find('main.question');

      var content = $('<section>').addClass('col-md-8 content').html(body);
      var footer = $(question).find('footer');

      container = $(container).append(sidebar).append(content).append(footer)

    $('main.bottom').append(container);
  });
```

How can I access the returned values of `$.map`? `$()` doesn't appear to work.

<strike>I'm using $.map in an AJAX request. `questions` prepares data for DOM insertion by wrapping the data in the appropriate DOM elements. `generateItem` is a generic function that preps the data based on whether the item is a question or an answer.</strike>

```
var questions = $.map(response.items, function(item, index){
  return generateItem(response.items,item,index);
});
```

I would like to iterate over `questions` so I can add elements to the DOM by section (e.g. add header to the left, main to the right, footer underneath them) for each object. (I do this outside of the first $.map because I don't want to add questions and answers the same way).

The problem is that jQuery's $.map returns a strange object, and I can't access the innerHTML values.

```
var tidyResponses = $.map(questions, function(question,index) {
  console.log(question) => [prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1], context: document, selector: "row", jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function…]
  => [prevObject: x.fn.x.init[1], context: document, selector: "row", jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function…]
});
```

Anyone know what kind of object $.map returns, and how one can interact with it? I tried to use jQuery selectors in `tidyResponses` to manipulate each question, but it failed.

Comment: `$.map()` returns an array -  `Translate all items in an array or object to new array of items.`

Comment: what is the value returned by `generateItem`? - looks like it is returning an jQuery object

Comment: I think the problem is, you are returning a jQuery object from `generateItem` and is trying to access the `.innerHTML` property of `questions` inside the second `.map()` handler.

Since it looks like `question` is a jQuery object, it will not have `innerHTML` property, it has a `.html()` method which allows you to get/set the `innerHTML`

Comment: Hi Arun thanks for all your comments. it returns a jQuery object that looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4ufhP/

Comment: then in the second iteration what do you want to do

Comment: In the second iteration I want to split each question into three sections: header, body and footer. But I can't access the elements within ```question``` with jQuery. Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/4ufhP/1/ In this example, all of the DOM elements are missing the content from ```question```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$.each`

```
$($.map(function(...) {
  return ...;
})).each(function(item) {
  // Do something
});
```

- [`jQuery.each`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)
- [`jQuery.map`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)